# Error when using the bfastlite function/time-series object?

Tags: r, time-series, raster

In `R`, I am using the `bfast` package to time-series raster data obtained from NASA Black Marble, monthly images (VNP46A3). I created 12 images for the year 2019. Each monthly study site contains NA values, but according to Masiliunas et al. (2021), BFAST Lite should handle the NA values. Below is a time-series plot:
[image: time-series plot]

What I have done so far is this (among my many tries):

**1st try**

```
# load libraries
library(terra)
library(stats)
library(bfast)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)
library(stlplus)

# set working directory
wd <- "path/"

# load the monthly raster files as list
l <- list.files(path = paste0(wd), pattern = "tif$", all.files = TRUE,
                      full.names = FALSE)

# convert the list to raster stack
r <- rast(paste0(wd, l))

# convert the raster stack to to matrix
m <- terra::as.matrix(r)

# convert the matrix to timeseries matrix
tm <- ts(data = m, start = c(2019, 1), end = c(2019, 12), frequency = 12, class = "ts")

class(tm)
[1] "ts"

# typed in Console
tm
         pred pred pred pred pred min pred pred pred pred min min
Jan 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
Feb 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
Mar 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
Apr 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
May 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
Jun 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
Jul 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
Aug 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
Sep 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
Oct 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
Nov 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
Dec 2019  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN

# Detect breaks
bp <- bfastlite(
  tm,
  formula = response ~ trend + harmon,
  order = 3,
  breaks = "LWZ",
  na.action = na.omit,
  stl = "both",
  decomp = "stl",
  h = 0.15,
  level = 0,
  type = "OLS-MOSUM"
)
```

The `bfastlite` gives the following error:

> Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object

**2nd try**

```
library(terra)
library(stats)
library(bfast)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)
library(stlplus)

wd <- "C:/Users/nikos/OneDrive/Desktop/tst/la/"

l <- list.files(path = paste0(wd), pattern = "tif$", all.files = TRUE,
                      full.names = FALSE)

r <- raster::stack(paste0(wd, l))

d <- c("2019-01-01", 
       "2019-02-01", 
       "2019-03-01", 
       "2019-04-01", 
       "2019-05-01", 
       "2019-06-01", 
       "2019-07-01", 
       "2019-08-01", 
       "2019-09-01", 
       "2019-10-01", 
       "2019-11-01", 
       "2019-12-01")

m <- raster::as.matrix(r)

bfastts(m, d, type = c("regular", "30-day"))
```

And this gives me this error:

> Error in if (type == "irregular") { : the condition has length > 1

Also, I tried to create a time-series matrix using the `zoo` and `terra` package wihtout luck.I have seen examples on GIS SE or SO, which I tried to implement but without success.

How can I convert my raster stack to a time-series object such as I can use it directly to the `bfastlite` function?

The dataset can be downloaded from my [GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V115zpdU2-5fXssI6iWv_F6aNu4E5qA7?usp=sharing).

I am using Windows 11, R 4.3.2. and RStudio 2023.09.1 Build 494.